# How does Worldviz Vizard compares to Panda3D and Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, 3d-engine, panda3d

Is anybody familiar with Worldviz-Vizard's 3D engine for python? How does it compare to Panda3D? I have a feeling that it might be easier to learn but far more limited. They only support python 2.4 which also makes me not want to try it.

Comment: Good god, look at those prices! I haven't heard of Worldviz before now, so won't formally answer. I endorse Panda3D wholeheartedly.

Comment: That is exactly what made me come and ask. Either these guys have something awesome to charge almost 10,000 or they are crazy.

Comment: There are a few different options for licensing. The full dev one is expensive, but not unreasonable and it's not your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Worldviz Vizard or Panda3D but it seems to me like you would have to reinvent the wheel to use Pygame for 3D.

Another Option:[Unity.](http://unity3d.com/unity/)
I'm not terribly experienced with this either but I heard it's good.

Answer (score 2):

Been using Vizard for various VR and AR development for about 3 yrs now - it's NOT unity - i.e. a web enabled game engine (excellent though it is) - what Vizard provides is a highly optimized OpenGL engine, wrapped in user friendly python scripting environment BUT on top of this you get the ability to seamlessly distribute your simulations over a cluster or a network. Vizard keeps all things completely synched - invisible to the user. Connects to pretty much all known VR tracking equipment and display periphals and standard gaming equipment is also supported (Wiimote & Kinnect). Native support for frame sequential, side-by-side and anaglyph stereo, spatial sound engine and the ability to extend it with C and C++ plugins or GLSL shaders.

Didn't actually mean to write that much and I don't want to come across as a Vizard evangelist, it is not perfect, BUT comparing it to Panda3D, Unity or other game engines I feel is an unfair comparison - not like-for-like :o)

Answer (score 0):

I only used Vizard, and that for one small project.

It was easy to use, well documented, and had a good set of examples.